# Регулярное выражение - вырезать указанные символы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется регулярное выражение вида:

```
/[\0\x0B\t\n\r\f\a&=+%#<>"~:`@\?\[\]\{\}\|\^'\\]/
```

Но вырезает не все символы. Остаются:

```
/ . ; № * ! ()
```

Не могу корректно доработать выражение на удаление и этих символов. Прошу помощи

Comment: "Не могу корректно" - читать как "и не пробовал"? Просто добавьте каждый из символов в символьный класс и проэкранируйте ...

Comment: @DROP, где быдлокод? Есть конкретная задача - есть конкретное решение. Вопрос явно из разряда "сам не пытался даже разобраться", по этому не вижу смысла вдаваться в подробности.

Comment: @DROP, вы мне пишете, держу в курсе.

Comment: @MedvedevDev ваш "ответ" читать как "встал не с той ноги решил оторваться в комментариях"? Я не силен в этой теме, для меня это набор символов. Попробовал добавить нужные для вырезания символы, мой вариант не работал. Не желаете подсказывать, проходите мимо пожалуйста.

Comment: @DROP нужно оставить латиницу/кириллицу/цифры. Сейчас выражение работает, но оставляет ненужные символы, указанные выше. Нужно просто добавить к вырезке их, и все

Comment: @MedvedevDev в том и дело, что с регулярками я вообще не работал, но здесь потребовалось решить внезапно возникшую проблему, пришлось обратиться за помощью. Разные ситуации бывают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пойти от обратного - вместо перечисления символов для удаления, в символьный класс можно записать символ отрицания `^`, за которым перечислить набор символов, которые нужно оставить. Например, вам нужно удалить всё, кроме буквенных символов и цифр - тогда шаблон можно записать так: `'~[^\pL\d]~u'`. На php решение можно записать так:

```
$str = "\0\x0B\t\n\r\fHe&=+%#<l>\"~:`@?[l]{o}|^'\\ 5678м:?*/и.;№*!(р)";

echo preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]~u', '', $str);
```

Результат:

```
Hello5678мир
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш вариант помог

Comment: теперь да) Рейтинг теперь позволяет)